# How to point to my host but keep my alias?

Tags: domain-name-system, hostname

I bought my domain (let's say `example.com`) from namecheap and added a subdomain to my blog hosted at heroku. The associated host record looks like this:

```
Type: CNAME
Host: blog
Target: tomyblog.herokuapp.com
```

Now when I go to `blog.example.com` it acts like a redirect, it changes the address to the location bar to `tomyblog.herokuapp.com`. I want it to retain `blog.example.com` in the location bar since it's the address the user is supposed to see, not from where I'm serving the content.

I have read a few documentations where some suggested to use `NS` records, but that's not available to namcheap, so I can't really test. It only offers `A`, `AAA`, `SRV` and `CNAME` types of records.

Comment: This is not done in DNS. It is done in your web application.

Comment: I added `blog.example.com` to my web app too.

Comment: Yet that's what's happening here though, or at least that's what it seems like.

Answer (score 4):

The premise behind this question is incorrect. The CNAME does not act as a redirect. A redirect at the web server acts as a redirect.

**Update**: Your web server is sending this:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: Cowboy
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: Express
Location: https://blog-onushshar.herokuapp.com/
Vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 71
Date: Wed, 30 Sep 2015 14:50:32 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur

Moved Permanently. Redirecting to https://blog-onushshar.herokuapp.com/
```

You need to investigate its configuration.

Comment: Well I assume even if the premise is incorrect, the problem is still there. All I said, it was *acting* like a redirect.

Comment: @Sayem With your real domain name, we could troubleshoot. Without it, all I can do is give you enough information to troubleshoot. You were looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was a generic problem, blog.onushshar.com there you go

Comment: @Sayem "Heroku | No such app"

Comment: edited the earlier answer. the root domain still points to an app that's yet to be created.

Comment: Do you have a certificate for `blog.onushshar.com`? If not, it can't work if you've specified secure only.